# How to iterate through an array in Postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

So I have created a follow/unfollow system like the one Twitter uses and I've been able to fetch the posts by the users, the currentLoggedIn user follows. This is the route that I'm calling:

```
const posts = await Post.find({ user: { $in: req.user.following } });
// Send response
res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: posts });
```

`req.user.following` comes from an array containing all of the users(again) the loggedIn user follows. This array of objects is found on my Users model:

```
following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
```

Now in order for this to work, I need to use `user: { $in: req.user.following }` and it works but the problem arises when I try to use it in an API route. For instance, I face the above problem in the route below:

```
{{URL}}/api/v1/posts?user[in]=howtoIterateThroughArrayOnPostman?
```

This is exactly where I'm having issues!

Comment: Have you tried using a body response using something like bodyParser?

Comment: hey, don't worry. I fixed it already by changing the route to posts/timeline. Everytime I trigger tha API ednpoint, the posts by users are displayed which is exactly what I wanted...sorry for my grammer errors. I'm using my cellphone nd not looking to fix them. `router.route('/timeline').get(getPostsByFriends);`